# Risk neutrality in the recent PRIIPs regulation

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, value-at-risk

In the recent regulation ([link](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/jc_2016_21_final_draft_rts_priips_kid_report.pdf) pag 31 point 12) is reported the VaR according to Cornish Fisher. Is this a real world measure?

By making computation I have seen that they assume an average return that is null. But this formula is still real world? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Point 9. above seems to imply it's a real world measure based on 5 years worth of historical returns.